# Squeeze Theorem to find $\lim_{x\to \infty}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \sin\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$

The answer is 1 but I don't understand why. Can someone show me the steps they took to arrive at this solution?

Comment: MathJax: to get the denominator right, put it in curly brackets {}.  Best to do this for the numerator too.  Thus: \frac{1}{x^2}.

Comment: why do you need the squeeze theorem at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
x^2\,\sin\frac1{x^2}=\dfrac{\sin\dfrac1{x^2}}{\dfrac1{x^2}}.
$$

Comment: This is what I tried earlier. After evaluating I ended up with $$\frac{\sin0}{\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

Comment: You should think of this as $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}$

Comment: Ohhhhh wow my mind has been blown

Comment: Ok wait. Why am I able to think of it as $\lim_{y\to 0}$? How does $\infty$ become 0?

Comment: Because $x^2$ goes to $1/y$ (or $y$ comes from $1/x^2$)

Comment: You should prove to yourself as a lemma that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(1/y)$ exists and when they do, they are equal. Also, the squaring doesn't really affect these limits.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite this expression as $$\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
and note that $\frac{1}{x^2}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to squeeze,
use
$z-\frac{z^3}{3}
< \sin z 
< z
$
for
$0 < z < \pi/2$
(actually,
for *all* $z$
since it is an
enveloping series).

Then,
if 
$\frac1{x^2}
< \pi/2$,
or
$x > \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$,
$\frac1{x^2} 
>\sin{\frac1{x^2}}
> \frac1{x^2}-\frac1{3x^4}
$
so
$1 
>x^2\sin{\frac1{x^2}}
> 1-\frac1{3x^2}
$.

To show
$z-\frac{z^3}{3}
< \sin z 
< z
$
for
$0 < z < \pi/2$,
start with
$\cos z < 1$
(which follows from
$\sin^2 z + \cos^2 z = 1$).
Integrate 
(all integrations are from
$0$ to $z$)
to get
$z > \sin z$.
Integrate again to get
$\frac{z^2}{2} > 1-\cos z$
or
$\cos z > 1-\frac{z^2}{2}$.
Integrate again to get
$\sin z > z-\frac{z^3}{3}
$.
(If you are worried about the
strict inequalities,
use non-strict - the result follows just as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show this is the usage of l'hospital's rule:

$\lim_{x \to \infty } x^2 sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) = \lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{sin(\frac{1}{x^2})}{\frac{1}{x^2}} =\lim_{x \to \infty } cos(\frac{1}{x^2})*\frac{-2}{x^3}*\frac{x^3}{-2}=\lim_{x \to \infty } cos(\frac{1}{x^2})=cos(0)=1$